# Very Slow Google Admin SDK Responses - Is it a technical issue?

Tags: google-api, google-apps

We are experiencing slowness in push notifications when using Google Apps Admin SDK API channels, for the following API's:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly,
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.security,
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.reports.audit.readonly
```

Slowness is a response every 20 mins after an event. This is generally unheard of for most Google Apps API's which are often lightening fast.

So my question is? Is this standard for the Google Apps Admin SDK? Has anyone else experience this issue?

If Google is listening - Help please! :-)

Jamie

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question: 
After extensive research and assistance from Google's Tech team, the following information came to light. 
The delay I described is expected as per the following link: 
https://www.google.com/url?hl=en&q=https://support.google.com/a/answer/7061566&source=gmail&ust=1472481859967000&usg=AFQjCNEpwbP6ZBUFyVOBOl8VVONAsGvKLQ